# Setting text from an xml file

Tags: xml, android-edittext

This may seem like a stupid question, but I'm stuck.  I have a string.xml in the values folder.  In this xml, I have some string names/values.

How do I set the string name value to an editText programmatically?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic and has as many answers in the site.

Try this.

```
EditText sampleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_sample_text);
sampleEditText.setText(getString(R.string.sampletext)); // R.string.<<string name>>
```